Flutter iOS: saving password in a webview
Given flutter-ios application with WKWebview that opens my website. Website URL is defined in associated domains plist setting + there is an AASA file.
There are email & password fields in the website that can be autofilled and this works - if I save email & password in Safari and then open my App it allows me to paste them.
But for some reasons if I do the login in the app (with new credentials) it doesn't prompt me to 'save password' like in Safari. Android prompts me but iOS doesn't. How to bring prompt 'save password' in iOS? What am I missing?
